# Is there a way to calculate the max of a sum in SQL?

Tags: sql, hive

I have three columns, sending organization, receiving organization and number of partecipants. How can I show, for each sending organization, the receiving organization with biggest number of partecipants?
Some rows have the same values for Sending and Receiving, so I have to sum the partecipants for that rows.

Es:

| SENDING | RECEIVING | PARTECIPANTS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 10 |
| A | C | 9 |
| A | B | 2 |
| B | C | 11 |
| B | D | 4 |
| B | D | 5 |
| C | E | 1 |

| Expected output | : |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | C |
| C | E |

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way will be to use a window function:

`SELECT sending,  FIRST_VALUE(receiving) OVER ( PARTITION BY sending ORDER BY partecipants DESC ) receiving FROM ttable GROUP BY sending`

Actually I did not get the part of your question concerning some sums of values. Should you have to do them you can replace `ttable` with a subquery `(SELECT SUM(...) ....)`

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this query was tested in MySQL, not Hive.

You can do:

```
select *
from (
  select sending, receiving, 
    rank() over(order by sum(partecipants) desc) as rk
  from t
  group by sending, receiving
) x
where rk = 1
```